# Perl insert new line between every }{ match

Tags: json, perl

I have a text file which contains a large amount of JSON objects and It hasn't been created with new lines or any separator between to the objects.

Currently I am using:

```
perl -e '$/ = "}{"; print "$_\n" while <>' file.txt > out.txt
```

But this causes malformed data as when the file gets split on new line the JSON objects will be missing the opening `{` as the new line gets placed after the `{`character.

Is there a way to insert the new line replacement between the `}{` match such as `}\n{`.

The file is quite large so I cant manually do it.

Doesn't have to be in Perl, can be in something more suited to the task.

Comment: Could you please post some example input for testing purposes?

Comment: Also, how often do you need to do this? Would a code editor feature or plugin do the trick? Eclipse and Sublime Text can do this; chances are Notepad++ and others can as well.

Comment: The question is, is that valid? json_xs doesn't think so... `cat json.json | json_xs -f json -t json-pretty` gives `garbage after JSON object, at character offset 13 (before "{"bar":"baz"}{"bo":"...") at /home/foo/...`

Comment: @MarkA.Fitzgerald Please don't add irrelevant tags. The [tag:code-formatting] tag wiki says "Code formatting is the way to format the source code of programs,using spaces and tabs, improving legibility of source code." This question is about fixing invalid JSON data, not formatting source code for readability.

Comment: Oversight on my part, @ThisSuitIsBlackNot. I thought he was prettifying JSON; turns out he's correcting invalid JSON. Sorry about that. :) It wasn't so that that was the case without example input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't just `print`. Substitute the newline in between the `}` and `{`. The `while` needs a block now because the last `s///` fails, so doing `s/// && print while <>` doesn't work.

```
$ cat json.json
{"foo":"bar"}{"bar":"baz"}{"bo":"shizzle"}
$ perl -e '$/ = "}{"; while (<>) { s/\}\{$/}\n{/; print; }' json.json 
{"foo":"bar"}
{"bar":"baz"}
{"bo":"shizzle"}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat in.json
{"a":"b","c":"d"}{"e":"f","g":"h"}

$ perl -MJSON::XS -0777ne'
   my $parser = JSON::XS->new->utf8;
   $parser->incr_parse($_);
   while ( my $obj = $parser->incr_parse() ) {
      print( $parser->encode($obj), "\n" );
   }
' in.json
{"c":"d","a":"b"}
{"e":"f","g":"h"}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ echo '{"a", "b", "c"}{42, "omg", "nyan"}{"no", "please", "stop"}' | perl -e '$/ = "}"; $\ = "}\n"; chomp and print while <>'
{"a", "b", "c"}
{42, "omg", "nyan"}
{"no", "please", "stop"}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with nested objects, e.g. `{ "foo": { "bar": "baz" } }`. Also, your examples (e.g. `{"a", "b", "c"}`) aren't valid JSON.

Comment: Yet it answers op's question, doesn't it?

Comment: Not if they have nested objects in their data.

Comment: Surely not if. From the fact that unwanted newline is the only complaint, I conclude this is not important.

Comment: Sorry, but you're wrong. The OP is parsing a file line-by-line, where each line must contain a valid JSON object. Inserting an extra newline in the middle of an object creates two lines of invalid JSON, which could only be parsed by an incremental parser like in [ikegami's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37215481/176646). And if you have to use an incremental parser anyway, there's no point in using your solution in the first place.

Comment: "The OP is parsing a file line-by-line, where each line must contain a valid JSON object."

Oh, really? Is it how you read the phrase "It hasn't been created with new lines or any separator between to the objects"?

Please consider it again. Op's infile is not a JSON file. It contains many JSON objects. Its each line contains many JSON objects. What contains a single object per line is the file he wants to create to write all this mess to. You are wrong. Can you stop arguing for no reason?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it manually with the search and replace tool.
Example:
Search for : "}{"
Replace with "}^p{" ( in Word ^p is new line)